# Convert generic IList<CustomType> to array?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have an IList which contains a custom type. One of the properties of that custom type is called **ID**. How could I convert that without using a for loop? The array should not be of the CustomType, but if the type of **ID**, which is int.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Try:

`sourceList.Select(i => i.ID).ToArray();`

Where `sourceList` is your list of type `IList<CustomType>.`

Comment: This returns a nullable, doesnt it? The method I am calling with this array doesnt take nullable types...what do I have to change?

Comment: @grady - The returned array is not a collection of nullable ints, it will be a `int[]` type, not `int?[]`. In fact, if you this code 'int?[] newArray = ......' then it will fail.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The compiler complains about it...I have a method which gets an array of ints and there the error is thrown.

Comment: @grady, this would only return nullable ints if the type of ID was a nullable int. If ID is int? and you want int, you would want to create a chain like `sourceList.Where(i => i.ID.HasValue).Select(i => i.ID.Value).ToArray();` The `Where` eliminates any IDs that may not have values, and `Select` will extract the int values.